# How does the focus-directrix definition of a conic section apply to a circle?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, curves

One of the definitions of a conic section is that the conic section is a locus of points whose distance to the focus $F$ is a constant multiple of distance between them and the directrix $D$, i.e.

$e = \frac{d(P,F)}{d(P, D)}$

Where $e$ is eccentricity. It is said that the eccentricity of a circle is $0$, which means:

$0 = \frac{d(P,F)}{d(P, D)}$

therefore,

$d(P,F)=0$

What confuses me about this, is that, unlike with other conic sections, where there would be infinite number of points $P$ which satisfy the given equation, it seems that the only point that satisfies this equation is the point $P=F$. Yet, the circle is composed of infinite points, which is contradictory. Can someone explain what is the geometric interpretation of this, and where I'm wrong?

Comment: *"Therefore, $d(P,F)=0$"* ... **or** $d(P,D) = \infty$! The directrix of a (non-point) circle is "at infinity". In this case, the focus-directrix definition isn't helpful, since it can't distinguish between circles with the same center.

Comment: Thanks! I don't like using infinity in this context, but I guess that is the only explanation...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the following illustration of a triple-family of conics, each with a common focus and matching eccentricities, but with distinct directrices. (The animation oscillates between eccentricities $0$ and $2$.)

[image]

As each conic gets more circular, its directrix moves further away. Consequently, it's not unreasonable to say that, as a limiting case, a (non-degenerate) circle, which has eccentricity $0$, has its directrix "at infinity", which is consistent with the relation

$$\text{eccentricity} = \frac{\text{distance from point to focus}}{\text{distance from point to directrix}} \tag{$\star$}$$

Of course, this makes a directrix completely useless for uniquely determining a circle, since the three concentric circles shown have the same fixed focus and "the same" infinitely-distant directrix. (Another wrinkle: A circle's directrix is really "at infinity" *in any direction*; so, it's really an *indeterminate* element.)

Otherwise, you're correct that, for a given (not-at-infinity) line and a given (not-at-infinity) focus, relation $(\star)$ with eccentricity $0$ defines a point-circle (ie, a circle of radius $0$) at the focus/center. (Related wrinkle: For such a circle, *any* line not passing through the focus/center serves as a directrix.)

---

This is one of the ways conics sections force people to confront ---and embrace--- infinity. As above, the key to understanding is to consider any particular conic, not as an isolated curve, but as part of an appropriate *family* of curves.

Comment: Excellent answer. In the illustration, the directrices appearing to come closer together as the conics become hyperbolas, and then appearing to space out when they became circles seemed to pose a problem; the directrices seemed to become more separate and not the "same"(and therefore useless in distinguishing different-sized circles) as you termed them. I suppose this is resolved by the fact that since infinity is not really a defined quantity, information on all three directrices is equally rendered nil there, and thus directrices are useless. Is that the case?

Comment: @harry: Yes, directrices of circles are pretty useless for distinguishing different-sized instances. However, (in a manner of speaking) the directrices actually converge to "the same line" once they reach infinity. (Infinity is cool like that.) The best context for this kind of discussion is [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry), where "the line at infinity" is fully embraced as a peer of old-fashioned lines.